# PostgresSQL dump file is breaking because of apostrophes and other unescaped chars?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

I have a docker container running remotely that I am trying to dump the sql data from, like so:

```
docker exec -t test_db pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql
```

When I try to run this dump file locally using the command

```
psql reports < dump_31-10-2017_14_38_13.sql
```

I get errors like this:

> Expected " char
>
> invalid command \N
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "il"
> LINE 1: il faut un ticket parking pour qu'il s'ouvre 750 1000 8 0 f

On inspection of the dump file using Intellij, the syntax highlighting shows there is breakage in the data ( caused by emojis, apostrophes and other characters)

[image]

How can I prevent this in postgreSQL when dumping the data?

PostgreSQL version : **9.5.7**

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error is generally the fallout of a previous SQL CREATE statement that fails. The first error mentioned : `Expected " char` could be something about a table not being created, and as a result the following `COPY` into that table would fail, and all data after that would be interpreted as SQL which would massively fail.

`invalid command \N` is also a sign of that, since `\N` represents NULL in COPY data, and this error occurs when psql confuses out-of-sync COPY data with backslash-starting meta-commands.

You could reload your dump with `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on` and focus on the first error.